# Easy Shell keyboard shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

Are there any shortcuts for opening terminal and explorer from Eclipse when using Easy Shell (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) that you know of?

I know some of the other tools provide that option (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+X</kbd> for explorer) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

EasyShell 2.x working with Eclipse 4.6 Neon now has a context menu [Context Menu (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ejap.png) and the shortcuts are:

**Alt + E**: [Main popup menu (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8TBs.png)

**Alt + Shift + E**: execute multiple commands for selection(s)

Shortcuts that executes the command directly if only one defined or opens a popup menu like **Alt + E** reduced for category:

**Alt + O**: Open Here (shell)

**Alt + R**: Run with (shell)

**Alt + X**: Explore

**Alt + C**: Copy to Clipboard

**Alt + U**: User defined category

Special not available for all OS:

**Alt + D**: Open with Default application

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for EasyShell, however since Eclipse Luna, there is a [*Show In > System Explorer*](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_whatsnew.html) command. On any selection that can be translated into a file system location you can press <kbd>Alt+Shift+W</kbd> and select the *System Explorer* menu entry.

You can also directly assign a key binding to the *System Explorer* command in the preferences. Therefore, open the Preferences dialog and select *General > Keys*, enter 'system' in the filter input field and assign a key binding of your choice to the *Show In (System Explorer)* entry.

The program that should be executed when the *System Explorer* command is invoked can be changed in the *General > Workspace* preference page.